# Touchpad left-click button not working

Tags: windows, windows-10, touchpad

I cannot click anywhere with my touchpad's left-click button. I cannot also tap on the touchpad to click. My computer is a Lenovo G50 - 45 PC running windows 10.

I have already searched online and tried (in powershell):

- `sfc /scannow`
- `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`
- `Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers    | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage`
- `DisableDevelopmentMode -Register    "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`

But nothing seems to work. I have also tried to restart my computer multiple times, but the problem still persists. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

The problem seems to have been a hardware issue, and has apparently gone away on its own.

Comment: You can eliminate software problems by booting an alternative OS, such as an installation disc. If the pad still doesn't work, you have a hardware failure. If so, your cheapest work round/solution will be an external USB mouse.

Comment: Well, the touchpad button has gone bad and your tap to click option is turned off.

Comment: You can try to install the latest driver. On this [page](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/it/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/g50-45-notebook-lenovo/downloads) under Mouse and Keyboard download Touchpad Driver (Elan, Synaptics) and install it.